# Odoo python programming language

Tags: python, odoo-10

In V10, How can I put control on generation of Automatic sequence numbers ? For example, If we take Employee Id. When we create Employee Id, a sequence like EMP-0001 is generated. Suppose we discarded it without Saving. Next time when we create a new Employee Id the sequence we are getting is EMP-0002. How to prevent this? Please give the answer in odoo 10

Comment: Your title does not reflect your question. Please [edit] it and make it more descriptive.

Answer (score 0):

You should not take sequence in default parameter other wise system will take sequence when you click on create button.

You should write sequence logic in create method.

Ex:

```
@api.model
def create(self, vals):
    if vals.get('name', 'New') == 'New':
        vals['name'] = self.env['ir.sequence'].next_by_code('sale.order') or 'New'
    return super(sale_order,self).create(vals)
```

In above example system will read sequence when you sale it.

You can find same reference in sale order base module.

This may help you.

Comment: this method returns the error. create method takes only two arguments.how to call method in field.

Comment: @api.model
    def create(self, vals):
        if vals.get('barcode', 'New') == 'New':
            vals['barcode'] = self.env['ir.sequence'].next_by_code('emp.code') or 'New'
        return super(HrEmployee,self).create(vals)

Comment: barcode = fields.Char(string="Badge ID",required=True,default=create)

Comment: i write this code hr_attendence module in employee.py

Comment: hr_employee.py,

Comment: You need to remove default=create  parameter, create method will call when you click on save button...

Comment: ya . i remove the default = create parameter, that method is not set to the barcode field.

Comment: Either You should remove if condition from create method or set default='New' in the field.because if condition is True then system will execute sequence get code...

Comment: i removed the if condition in create method .but emp id is not generated

Comment: You need to pass sequence code to get sequence , can you verify your sequence code ?

Comment: here problem is when i write the method is      def default_random(self):
        print "*********"
        Empid = None
         #res = super(HrEmployee,self).create(vals)
        Empid= self.env['ir.sequence'].next_by_code('emp.code')
        print Empid
        return Empid
                            Empid = fields.Char(string = "Empid",required=True,default=default_random)
that time sequence no will come but when we click the discard button sequence no incremented

Comment: code is very length .stack over flow not accepted length

Answer (score 0):

First you have to insert a field for the Employee ID.Like below !

```
name = fields.Char(string="Employee ID", Index= True, default=lambda self:('New'), readonly=True)
```

Afterwards you have to create a file named as ir_sequence.xml in views folder.Write the code as like below.

```
<odoo>
    <data>
    <record id="seq_bi_ticket" model="ir.sequence">
            <field name="name"> [NAME] </field>
            <field name="code">[class_name]</field>
            <field name="prefix"> EMP </field>
            <field name="padding"> 5 </field> 
            <!-- The length of the number you need is 5 -->
            <field name="company_id" eval="False"/>
        </record>
    </data>
</odoo>
```

Also have to write function inside the main class along with that field which I said above.The function code is here below:

```
@api.model
    def create(self, vals):
        if vals.get('name', _('New')) == _('New'):
            if 'company_id' in vals:
                vals['name'] = self.env['ir.sequence'].with_context(force_company=vals['company_id']).next_by_code('[CLASS_NAME]') or _('New')
            else:
                vals['name'] = self.env['ir.sequence'].next_by_code('[CLASS_NAME]') or _('New')     
        result = super([CLASS_NAME], self).create(vals)
        return result
```

It's over . Thus you go !!!